# ExtJS Combobox item do not have any style applied

Tags: extjs, combobox

Whenever I expand the combobox and list up all possible items, they look like they have no style applied. (e.g. no background, hover-effect, ...).

All I want is just the simple hover effect which is provided by the kitchen sink example page.
I attached a small screenshot to make the issue clearer.
[image: combobox problem]
As you can see, the two items 'Daniel Moos' & 'Timon Guggenbühl' do not have any style applied.

this is the code where I insert the combobox into my window:

```
    items:[
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        id: 'groupleader',
        fieldLabel: 'Gruppenleiter',
        store: Ext.create('Desktop.Caregroup.store.employeeStore'),
        displayField: 'Fullname',
        valueField: 'id',
        emptyText: 'Gruppenleiter auswählen',
        queryMode: 'local',
        editable:false
    },
```

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: If you are using Sencha cmd and you use a component the first time, the css is only available after building the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you add combo (or any other component) to the application. The reason is that even development app uses css and resources of the production version (after build).

When a component is added, css and resources are not available before you build the app.

Minimum to execute (sometimes works):

```
sencha app refresh
sencha ant sass
```

Build always works:

```
sencha app build
```